# SQL Server Query - Join tables to display what doesn't exist in one of them

Tags: sql, sql-server

I would like to join two tables in SQL and have the outcome display the value of table 1 where there's no match in table 2.

Example:

Table1

```
Person  |January|February|March|April| May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December|
Person 1|      1|       2|    3|    4|   5|   6|   7|     8|        9|     10|      11|      12|
Person 2|      1|       2|    3|    4|   5|   6|   7|     8|        9|     10|      11|      12|
Person 3|      1|       2|    3|    4|   5|   6|   7|     8|        9|     10|      11|      12|
```

Table2

```
Person  |Month|
Person 1|    1|
Person 1|    3|
Person 1|    5|
Person 1|    7|
Person 1|    9|
Person 1|   11|
Person 2|    2|
Person 2|    4|
Person 2|    6|
Person 2|    8|
Person 2|   10|
Person 2|   12|
Person 3|    1|
Person 3|    2|
Person 3|    3|
Person 3|    4|
Person 3|    5|
Person 3|    6|
Person 3|    7|
Person 3|    8|
Person 3|    9|
Person 3|   10|
Person 3|   11|
Person 3|   12|
```

Desired Result

```
Person  |January|February|March|April| May|June|July|August|September|October|November|December|
Person 1|   NULL|       2| NULL|    4|NULL|   6|NULL|     8|     NULL|     10|    NULL|      12|
Person 2|      1|    NULL|    3| NULL|   5|NULL|   7|  NULL|        9|   NULL|      11|    NULL|
Person 3|   NULL|    NULL| NULL| NULL|NULL|NULL|NULL|  NULL|     NULL|   NULL|    NULL|    NULL|
```

So you can see that in Table 2, Person 1 only has ODD months, so that person should show all the EVEN months from Table 1 in the results since those months don't exist in Table 2.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: What you need to here is unpivot table1 so it is in the same normalized structure as table2, then a basic left join will accomplish this. https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure what the purpose of table 1 is here. Below is a query against table 2 that will tell you what months a person is in. This uses 1 for yes and 0 for no. I would recommend not using NULL for no as it should only show an absence of information. In this case we are confirming that the person is not listed for that month. I'm also unsure why you would want to post a 2 for February and a 3 for March when the column name will call out what month you are referencing.

```
DECLARE @Table2 TABLE (
Person VARCHAR(MAX)
,[Month] INT
)

INSERT @Table2 VALUES
('Person1',1)
,('Person1',3)
,('Person1',5)
,('Person1',7)
,('Person1',9)
,('Person1',11)
,('Person2',2)
,('Person2',4)
,('Person2',6)
,('Person2',8)
,('Person2',10)
,('Person2',12)
,('Person3',1)
,('Person3',2)
,('Person3',3)
,('Person3',4)
,('Person3',5)
,('Person3',6)
,('Person3',7)
,('Person3',8)
,('Person3',9)
,('Person3',10)
,('Person3',11)
,('Person3',12)

SELECT
    Person
    ,CASE
        WHEN Person IN (SELECT Person FROM @Table2 WHERE [Month] = 1) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS January
    ,CASE
        WHEN Person IN (SELECT Person FROM @Table2 WHERE [Month] = 2) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS February
    ,CASE
        WHEN Person IN (SELECT Person FROM @Table2 WHERE [Month] = 3) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS March
    ,CASE
        WHEN Person IN (SELECT Person FROM @Table2 WHERE [Month] = 4) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS April
    ,CASE
        WHEN Person IN (SELECT Person FROM @Table2 WHERE [Month] = 5) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS May
    ,CASE
        WHEN Person IN (SELECT Person FROM @Table2 WHERE [Month] = 6) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS June
    ,CASE
        WHEN Person IN (SELECT Person FROM @Table2 WHERE [Month] = 7) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS July
    ,CASE
        WHEN Person IN (SELECT Person FROM @Table2 WHERE [Month] = 8) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS August
    ,CASE
        WHEN Person IN (SELECT Person FROM @Table2 WHERE [Month] = 9) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS September
    ,CASE
        WHEN Person IN (SELECT Person FROM @Table2 WHERE [Month] = 10) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS October
    ,CASE
        WHEN Person IN (SELECT Person FROM @Table2 WHERE [Month] = 11) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS November
    ,CASE
        WHEN Person IN (SELECT Person FROM @Table2 WHERE [Month] = 12) THEN 1 ELSE 0
        END AS December
FROM @Table2
GROUP BY
    [Person]
```

Comment: Thanks! I will look into this first thing tomorrow and let you know.

Comment: Very nice! You are correct, Table1 is not even needed. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution using a pivot. The first cte (called Months) just makes a list from 1 - 12. The second cte creates an equivalent for your Table2. To get all the months Not in Table 2, cross join the first cte with table2, then except the values from table2.

Then pivot...

```
;With Months AS
(
SELECT 1 AS Level
UNION ALL
SELECT Level + 1 FROM Months
WHERE Level < 12
)
,cte AS
(
SELECT 'Person1' [Person],1 [Month]
UNION SELECT 'Person1',3
UNION SELECT 'Person1',5
UNION SELECT 'Person1',7
UNION SELECT 'Person1',9
UNION SELECT 'Person1',11
UNION SELECT 'Person2',2
UNION SELECT 'Person2',4
UNION SELECT 'Person2',6
UNION SELECT 'Person2',8
UNION SELECT 'Person2',10
UNION SELECT 'Person2',12
UNION SELECT 'Person3',1
UNION SELECT 'Person3',2
UNION SELECT 'Person3',3
UNION SELECT 'Person3',4
UNION SELECT 'Person3',5
UNION SELECT 'Person3',6
UNION SELECT 'Person3',7
UNION SELECT 'Person3',8
UNION SELECT 'Person3',9
UNION SELECT 'Person3',10
UNION SELECT 'Person3',11
UNION SELECT 'Person3',12
) 
Select * from 
(
    Select Distinct Person, Level [Month] FROM cte
    CROSS JOIN Months
    EXCEPT
    Select Person, Month from cte
) a
Pivot(MAX(Month) For Month in ([1],[2],[3],[4],[5],[6],[7],[8],[9],[10],[11],[12])) Pvt
```

Comment: Sorry, but this answer is static. What if I had 50,000 Persons?

Comment: Not static. Replace the second cte definition with a query selecting as many folks as you like...eg.`,cte as(select Person, Month from sometable)...`